# Recharts ComposedChart two different data types / data baselines (value / percentage)

Tags: reactjs, charts, weather, recharts

I'm doing a weather passion project thingie using React and Recharts and trying to cram temperature and rain to the same chart.

[image: Illustration]

Illustration also here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh3pk.jpg

You can see my dilemma. I would like to have the rain bars to start from the bottom X-Axis. But the value zero means the same thing for both chart types. Any way to overcome this, with some magical math or something?

Or having the datasets be of totally different types? Like using celsius degrees for the temperature values but percentage for the rain so that zero rain means no bar and 100% rain means full bar?

Or if Recharts cannot do this, I am up for a chart library that can.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out what I was looking for was another Y-axis, and recharts supports that. Here is the code for a working solution using recharts 1.8.5:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ComposedChart, XAxis, YAxis, Tooltip, Legend, CartesianGrid, Bar, Line } from 'recharts'

export default function App() {

  const data = [
    { time: "00:00", temp: -5, rain: 0 },
    { time: "03:00", temp: -2, rain: 0 },
    { time: "06:00", temp: -1, rain: 0 },
    { time: "09:00", temp: 0, rain: 0 },
    { time: "12:00", temp: 2, rain: 3 },
    { time: "15:00", temp: 4, rain: 10 },
    { time: "18:00", temp: 5, rain: 3 },
    { time: "21:00", temp: 3, rain: 0 },
    { time: "00:00", temp: 0, rain: 0 },

  ]

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ComposedChart width={730} height={250} data={data}>
        <XAxis dataKey="time" />
        <YAxis yAxisId={1} orientation="right" label={{ value: 'Rain mm', angle: -90 }} />
        <YAxis yAxisId={2} label={{ value: 'Temp', angle: -90 }} />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <CartesianGrid stroke="#f5f5f5" />
        <Bar yAxisId={1} dataKey="rain" barSize={40} fill="#413ea0" />
        <Line yAxisId={2} type="monotone" dataKey="temp" stroke="#ff0000" />
      </ComposedChart>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Illustration]